# Reding two JSON data from server-side DataTables Editor

Tags: javascript, json, database, datatables, serverside-javascript

I am trying to read data from server-side to client from two JSON objects. I am trying to populate my datatble using some information from both the JSON objects. I am able to load both the data(data and data1) but there is a parse error.

The data loaded looks like this :

***  } { these two brackets in bold is error ***

```
{
    "data": [{
        "starty": "100758"
    }, {
        "starty": "100759"
    }, {
        "starty": "100760"
 {
        "starty": "101043"
    }]
**} {**    this is the error, I want to remove this so it reads all as one 
    "data": [{
        "DT_RowId": "row_100758",
        "contract_bal": {
            "contract_id": "100758",
            "member_name": "Foodservice",
            "opt_one": "11970",
            "opt_two": "0",
            "opt_three": "0",
            "opt_four": "0",
            "opt_five": "0",
            "opt_six": "0",
            "monthly_input": "5231",
            "start_date": "2019-10-01",
            "end_date": "2020-09-30",
            "contractinfo_id_fk": "4",
            "product_code_fk2": "D2230"
        },
        "contract_info": {
            "contra_prod": "Tomatoes"
        },
        "products": {
            "product_name": " Chopped Tomatoes"
        }
    }, {
        "DT_RowId": "row_100759",
        "contract_bal": {
            "contract_id": "100759",
            "member_name": "Foodservice",
            "opt_one": "16970",
            "opt_two": "0",
            "opt_three": "0",
            "opt_four": "0",
            "opt_five": "0",
            "opt_six": "0",
            "monthly_input": "10200",
            "start_date": "2019-10-01",
            "end_date": "2020-09-30",
            "contract_id_fk": "4",
            "prcode_fk2": "D230"
        },
        "contr_info": {
            "contract_prod": "Tomatoes"
        },
        "products": {
            "product_name": " Tomatoes "
        }
    }]
    },
    "files": [],
    "searchPanes": {
        "options": []
    }
}
```

How do i read both of JSON objects on same file with out getting error?

Comment: DataTables expects to receive a single valid JSON object (not 2 separate objects concatenated together). You can merge 2 JSON objects, of course, but the result has to be a new valid JSON object (and it has to have a structure that DataTables can iterate over, to build the table rows).

Comment: There are other problems with the JSON in the question, apart from the one you mention. For example, here: `"starty": "100760" {...` - and the section at the end starting with `"files": []`. I assume you have control over the JSON which is being generated. Are you using a JSON library to generate the JSON, and a validator, such as [this](https://jsonlint.com/), to check it?